# Docker volume binding not working on Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, docker

I've noticed problems with the configuration of Docker volumes binding on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, installed from an ISO file downloaded from the official site: https://ubuntu.com/download/server.

The commands below can reproduce the problem.

Create a new directory with 777 access and a test file:

```
mkdir /tmp/ngdata
chmod 777 /tmp/ngdata
touch /tmp/ngdata/created_on_host
```

Next, I run a Docker container with volume binding:

```
docker run -v /tmp/ngdata:/ngdata:rw -d nginx
```

This command:

```
docker exec 7dfa35882407 ls /ngdata
```

returns nothing. Executing touch from within the container creates a file within the container:

```
docker exec <conainer hash> touch /ngdata/created_on_docker
docker exec <conainer hash> ls /ngdata
```

The second command returns: created_on_docker.

Running ls /tmp/ngdata on the host returns created_on_host.

It looks like there are problems with binding; the container stores files on its own file system, which is not bound to the host.

I have encountered this problem on at least two computers with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but on a Linode node running Ubuntu 22.04, everything works without the aforementioned issue.

Could you please guide me on what I can check to resolve the volume binding issue on my Ubuntu servers?

Comment: How was Docker itself installed? What does `docker version` output?

Comment: Thanks for hints :) I checked both options: without rw flag and Z flag unfortunately both did not work.

Comment: I installed Docker using the Ubuntu installer. One of the final steps during the installation process offers a choice of "standard" components, such as an SSH server and Docker. So, I used this method to install it. The version is "Docker version 24.0.5, build ced0996."

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. The problem lies somewhere in the Snap installation of Docker. Removing the Snap version of Docker and installing it based on the information from the official Docker page solved my problem.

- Follow the [uninstallation guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876116/how-to-remove-a-snap-application-docker-completely).
- Then the [docker installation guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).

Comment: Yes, because the `snap` version does not have access to system folders, like `/tmp`.

Comment: Good catch! I didn't think of Snap version of Docker.As @ArturMeinild said, Snap is a sandbox in itself. Normally Snap does not allow access to files and folders outside its sandbox system.